# Building dynamic shared library (.so, .dylib) using Makefile and gcc

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I would like to build shared library (`.so, .dylib)` with Makefile gcc. 
My library has references (symbols) from other shared library (other C project compiled to shared library).

I have such directory structure:

```
/c/
  /Project1/...
  /Project2/...
  ... 
  /unit_tests/...
  /comparers/...
```

Inside my `/comparers` directory I have such directory structure:
[image]

I have tried in order to compile unit_test shared library that depends on comparers shared library make something like this:

```
$(SHARED_LIBRARY): assertion.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o $(OUTPUT_LIB_DIR)/$(SHARED_LIBRARY) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/assertion.o $(COMPARERS_SHARED_LIB_PATH)
```

where:

```
COMPARERS_SHARED_LIB_PATH= ../comparers/output/debug/lib/libcomparers.so
```

But It doesn't work if I use static library path instead it compiles correctly. Why this doesn't work and how to make it working correctly?

**UPDATE: error message**

Above is building correctly but I assume it cause error at runtime! When I link the same way my executable target it also builds, but when running it gives such error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: output/debug/lib/libcomparers.so
  Referenced from: /Users/michzio/Developer/MyProjects/BachelorDegree/c/unit_tests/./output/debug/bin/unit_tests
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" ? not very helpful...

Comment: Post the error messages verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not post the error messages, there are a few errors that are immediately apparent.

One error is that you mix and match filenames with and without paths. E.g. `$(SHARED_LIBRARY)` is different from `$(OUTPUT_LIB_DIR)/$(SHARED_LIBRARY)` and `assertion.o` is different from `$(OUTPUT_DIR)/assertion.o`. You need to learn how to use [GNU make's automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to prevent such mistakes.

Another error is that the way you link to another shared library: the runtime linker searches for `../comparers/output/debug/lib/libcomparers.so` and that path is valid only when the current directory is something specific.

And linking normally uses `LDFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`.

One fix could be:

```
COMPARERS_SHARED_LIB_PATH := $(abspath ../comparers/output/debug/lib/libcomparers.so)

$(OUTPUT_LIB_DIR)/(SHARED_LIBRARY): $(OUTPUT_DIR)/assertion.o $(COMPARERS_SHARED_LIB_PATH)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

For a production build though, it needs to specify `-rpath` to other shared libraries using `$ORIGIN` relative paths, so that the runtime linker finds the required shared libraries relative to its user. And link to that shared library using `-L<path> -l<lib>` rather than the full path.